# Pythonic solution for conditional arguments

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a below function where infile is the parameter of func. Now I want to perform the below operation.

If infile = default, then do, df = pd.read_csv("/path/to/the/file/given/a.csv)
else, read the file path given to the infile.

```
def func(infile):
  if infile == default:
      df = pd.read_csv("/path/to/the/file/given/a.csv)
  else:
      df = pd.read_csv(infile)
```

This approach is working fine

Comment: What is the value of `default`?

Answer (score 1):

Default parameter in Python [function definition](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions) works like below:

```py
def func(infile="/path/to/the/file/given/a.csv"):
    df = pd.read_csv(infile)
```

> When one or more parameters have the form parameter = expression, the
>   function is said to have “default parameter values.” For a parameter
>   with a default value, the corresponding argument may be omitted from a
>   call, in which case the parameter’s default value is substituted. If a
>   parameter has a default value, all following parameters up until the
>   “*” must also have a default value — this is a syntactic restriction
>   that is not expressed by the grammar.

Comment: I need to have an option for infile parameter. For example, if infile ='Y', do this else do that

Comment: just implement as what you said, what's the problem you're facing?